# How to use RxJS "throttle" operator in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

Below is my component code where I am trying to use RxJS "throttle" operator.

```
import { Component , OnInit , OnChanges , DoCheck  } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/throttle';

@Component({
    selector:'rx1',
    template: `
    <h2> Rx1 Component </h2>
    <button name="btn" valur="click"> 
})

export class Rx1Component implements OnInit {   

    ngOnInit() {
        var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

        Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click')
            .throttle(1000) 
            .subscribe(() => console.log('clicked....'));
    }
}
```

The intention of this simple sample is to print "clicked...." only when there is a min gap of 1 sec between clicks.

But when I compile this code , it display below error and it points to ".throttle(1000)" line.

> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {}) => SubscribableOrPromise'.

What is the mistake I am doing.

Comment: Well, look at the documentation of throttle. It doesn't expect a duration as argument: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-throttle. Maybe you want throttleTime: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-throttleTime

Comment: What version of rxjs typescript declarations are you using?  Your code looks fine to me,  which leads me to believe the declaration file is bad.   Can you paste the throttle declaration from the typescript declaration file here also?

Comment: @JB Nizet    throttleTime has worked .

Comment: @Jeffrey Patterson version is 3.10.5

Comment: But from your description, it seems you need to use `debounceTime` and not `throttleTime`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have suggested `throttle()` takes as an argument an Observable not the duration. However, what you describe suits more for a `debounceTime()` operator.

One thing worth mentioning is that since you're using Angular2 you're **always using RxJS 5** and not the old RxJS 4. I guess you've found `throttle` here https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/throttle.md or http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html but these both describe RxJS 4.

The correct doc for RxJS 5 is http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-throttle and as you can see there're `throttle()` and `throttleTime()`.